Python typing of Callable with Concatenate and ParamSpec for child class functions in decorator?
I feel I'm not understanding something and don't know the correct way to typehint this.
I've got a parent class and a child class. I'm trying to create a decorator with ParamSpec so I gain access to args / kwargs and the return inside a decorated child class function where the first argument is of course always "self", and be able to do something inherited from the parent.
Something that looks like this:
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, Concatenate
from collections.abc import Callable

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")


class Parent:
    def parent_function(self, s:str):
        print("hola " + s)


def decorate(
    func: Callable[Concatenate[Parent, P], T]
) -> Callable[Concatenate[Parent, P], T]:
    def wrapper(self: Parent, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
        self.parent_function("there")
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


class Child(Parent):
    @decorate
    def child_function(self, s:str):
        print("hello " + s)

child = Child()
child.child_function("world")

Now, this works just fine of course (returns "hola there\nhello world\n") but MyPy complains on the "@decorate" because:

Argument 1 to "decorate" has incompatible type "Callable[[Child, str], Any]"; expected "Callable[[Parent, str], Any]"

I get this is a minimal example, but I'm not sure why it's complaining that Child isn't of type Parent here. Or if there's another way around it.
MyPy is perfectly happy if I get replace "Concatenate[Parent,p]" with "P" and just assert isinstance(args[0],Parent) inside wrapper, but I would prefer to use type hinting instead of a code assertions.

Argument types are contravariant. Therefore, you must either do Concatenate[Child, P] (because Child is the bottom of the type hierarchy) or make the callable generic in the instance (Concatenate[ParentT, P], where ParentT = TypeVar("ParentT", bound="Parent")). See mypy Playground.

Oh man, I didn't know that. That's quite unintuitive (to me), but thanks for the way to genericize rather than trying to think of creating some kind of combination of all possible child types :)

To feel the "why", consider a smaller case: Callable[[Parent], None]. What if your decorator calls func(Parent())? Child.method is only supposed to work on Child instances (for example, may rely on new attributes not existing on Parent), so this shouldn't be allowed.

I don't follow. Isn't that the whole point of inheritance and duck typing? To be able to use the parent methods from children. Inside the child method there might be child specific things, sure, but the decorator calling parent items shouldn't be a problem there?
